# Trying to build a Like/Unlike Button in Flutter Streambuilder - not working

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to get a like/unlike button in a newsfeed I am building in my app. I'm using streambuilder.

Here's the code for the button:

```
FlatButton(
                              child: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.thumb_up,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Like',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: isPostLiked == true ? () {
                                _firestore.collection('posts').document(postID).updateData({'likeCount' : postLikeCount - 1, 'likedBy' : FieldValue.arrayRemove(['${loggedInUser.email}'])});


                                isPostLiked = false;
                                print('USER HAS UNLIKED THIS POST');

                              } : () {
                                _firestore.collection('posts').document(postID).updateData({'likeCount' : postLikeCount + 1, 'likedBy' : FieldValue.arrayUnion(['${loggedInUser.email}'])});

                                isPostLiked = true;
                                print('USER HAS LIKED THIS POST');

                              },
                            ),
```

The isPostLiked is a bool, which I've set initially to be false `bool isPostLiked = false;`.

The issue that I have is that its only letting the user like post. It won't let the user unlike the post. It seems that its just not updating the `isPostLiked = true`, and that seems to be where I am going wring. Any ideas?

For a bit more context, here's some of the code of the Streambuilder widget that the FlatButton is nested in:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore
                  .collection('posts')
                  .orderBy('date', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    ),
                  );
                }
                final posts = snapshot.data.documents;
                List<Widget> postWidgets = [];
                for (var post in posts) {
                  bool isPostLiked = false;
...
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your onpressed into the following:

```
onPressed: () {
      if (isPostLiked) {
        // add your firebase code
        print('unlike');
      } else {
        // add your firebase code
        print('like');
      }
      isPostLiked = !isPostLiked;
    }
```

I tried it on dartpad and got the variable to change every time it presses.

Comment: Hi @nickypangers! Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your suggestion - it works fine if there is no firestore code in it, but as soon as firestore code is added in, it stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: @JasonLloyd try adding async after the (), like:
onPressed: () async { ... }

Comment: Hi @nickypangers just tried that, still not working unfortunately. It works fine if there's no firestore code - its really strange isn't it?!

Comment: @JasonLloyd Maybe you'll have to create an instance of Firestore inside the onPressed. Something like Firestore.instance.collection('posts').document(postID)... Edit it to fit your code.